# VS2012 random nonexistent errors in code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My VS2012 occasionally complains about errors that don't even exist in the code. For example:

[image]

Even though the function starts with `Private Function MyFunction()`, it seems that VS ignores it and does not let build, resulting in errors such as:

```
'End' statement cannot be used in class library projects.
```

Any ideas why it might be doing this or how to fix?

Comment: Try a Clean, then rebuilding.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks! I was thinking I might need a reinstall.

Comment: Any idea why it keeps doing that? I recall that I never had to clean and rebuild in the past. Just simply building the project would normally do the trick.

Comment: Not sure. From the position of the squiggly-line though it looks like it was reacting to "End" (possibly before it was "End Function")?

Comment: Just doesn't seem to be that particular line. It does that for any line of code change within my class file, requiring me to clean and rebuild for even changing or adding a variable name.